# excel ant selenium test

Tags: eclipse, apache, ant, selenium, automation

I have testcases in an excel file. 
A java program accesses that, and I run them on a browser using selenium RC.
Now, when I use ANT to generate an HTML report, it treats the entire thing as 1 test case.
is there a way to generate different test case reports in the same html ouput file?

Answer (score 0):

Use different test cases to access different part of your excel sheets.It might be repeatable to you but this is the only way if you want ant or junit to consider it different test cases.

OR

Right your own code for generating your customized reports in whatever format you want html or excel.

Comment: Any ways if your single java program is accessing your file, Your whole program will be called once only..so Ant can not do anything in that case..Better you go through some framework like Junit or TestNg..For your case TestNG have provided an annotation called as dataProvider which might help you a lot..